# Citrix thin clients and the use of of user or host based certificates. How does it work in this kind of environment?

Tags: certificate, citrix

Do citrix thin clients offer user or host based certs?

Is there some kind of third party service that can offer such.

Comment: Like this: http://www.citrix.com/ready/en/venafi-inc/venafi-encryption-director-certificate-manager

Comment: Thanks this was information but looking for something that's more directly related to xendesktop thin clients. However, this product was relevant for what I am trying to accomplish long term.